# React Native - Text component breaks boundaries and doesnt scale its size; behaves differently on ios & android

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to create a component that has a minHeight, but can scale if it's content get larger. Its content is a row containing an icon + text (Idea is that when icon size is slightly bigger it wouldn't immediately increase the height of the component).

First image below shows how it should look like and how it's displayed on the web, but on iOS and android it doesnt work as expected. Seems like the height of the view doesn't scale properly and instead keeps a fixed size + the icon will make it break boundries.
Try for yourself: https://snack.expo.dev/ZBTGBMLa9

---

How it should look like (and how it's displayed in the webview)

[image: Web]

How it actually looks like on iOS and android

[image: iOS]
[image: Android]

Code from this component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function TestComp({text, logo}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        {logo && <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/snack-icon.png')} /> }
        <Text>
          {text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    minHeight: 50,
    marginVertical: 10,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  content: {
    padding: 10,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  logo: {
    height: 28,
    width: 28,
    marginRight: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `Text` this style:

`js <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{maxWidth: '90%'}} >`